# 2FA Using A USB Key

Tags: usb, ppa

I would like to have a USB that would unlock my PC when I plug it in. I know questions have been asked about this before, but I have found no working solution. lib-pam has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. You can add a PPA to have it installed but it has not been updated in years. Is there any solution?

Comment: You can do it with a USB Yubikey, but I am not sure if you asking about a generic kind of USB. Yubikey instructions are here https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000011356-ubuntu-linux-login-guide-u2f

Comment: Yeah I would like to use a generic key.

Comment: Would something like this work? https://github.com/chadoe/luks-triple-unlock

The down side is that it doesn't look like it's actively maintained, and it works with luks disk encryption, not GDM login.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to achieve what you describe without knowing if you need to unlock the screen or decrypt your disk is to program a USB key (Yubikey) to automatically type your unlock password when the button is pressed. This way you can have long secure random passwords for both your LUKS encrypted disk and your screen lock password. This approach will work without changing any software in your computer because Yubikey can simulate a USB keyboard to type. However this is not very secure because anyone with access to your key can copy the password by connecting it to a computer. The right way to do it requires changing software to implement a cryptographic protocol between the host and the key. New operating systems will support FIDO U2F, Webauthn or similar standards to achieve what you describe in a real secure way. But you can use the automatically type password now if you get a Yubikey and you use the [personalization](https://developers.yubico.com/yubikey-personalization-gui/) tool available in Ubuntu Software.

Comment: One way to use a Yubikey to do sort of a 2FA is to type in one half of the password from memory, and let the Yubikey type the other half like you describe. This can make the overall password much stronger, and an attacker getting hold of the key can still not log in to your machine. However, with both ways, if you loose the key and don't have a backup, you're locked out.

Comment: While this is a good answer, I wish to use a generic USB not a yubikey.